# Two icons created when using two activities

Tags: android, kotlin, android-activity, android-manifest

Two icon created when i using Two activity Android Studio.
I don't know why is this.
I delete intent and I do some works but it's didn't worked.

I am creating one app.
And I run in physical device.
And that app has two icons.

Comment: Check if there are two `<intent-filters>` attributes for both the activities. Make only one activity as Main Launcher and the other Icon will be removed.

Comment: Edit your question and copy your manifest into the question. That's probably your problem.

Comment: I already removed one intent filter but didn't worked

Answer (score 0):

I find my problem and I will clear .
`

```
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>`
```

here you will two category . you will delete number two category .
This is our problem . android.intent.category.LAUNCHER this create a app icon for second activity.

Answer (score 0):

Just remove these lines from one of your two activities (if you have a SplashScreen and a MainActivity, remove them from your MainActivity)

```
        <intent-filter>
           <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
           <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
       </intent-filter>
```

Answer from https://stackoverflow.com/a/29735556/8577483